# Заполнение очереди из файла

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, очередь

Как заполнить стандартный контейнер *очередь* (`queue`) данными из файла с помощью стандартных алгоритмов?

Comment: в очереди какие элементы хранятся? числа, строки или ...?

Comment: целые числа @diraria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве альтернативного варианта предложу обойтись без вспомогательного контейнера и добавлять сразу в очередь с помощью [std::for_each/3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("number.txt");
    std::queue<int> Q;
    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
                  std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                  [&Q](int n)
    {
        Q.push(n);
    });

    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        std::cout << Q.front() << '\n';
        Q.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Например, заполните контейнер, а потом сделайте на его базе очередь:

```
ifstream in("file");

deque<int> D;

copy(istream_iterator<int>(in),istream_iterator<int>(),
     back_inserter(D));

queue<int> Q(D); // Можно move(D), если отдельный дек больше не нужен

while(!Q.empty())
{
    cout << Q.front() << endl;
    Q.pop();
}
```

Только стандартные алгоритмы :)

Ага, раз принят ответ, где допускается что-то кроме алгоритмов - то тогда все, конечно, гораздо проще:

```
for(int n; cin>>n;) Q.push(n);
```

Все, больше ничего не нужно.

Comment: См. дополненный ответ. В следующий раз просьба ставить ТЗ поточнее.